# The names of our god and meanings

Tags: genesis

From the bible I learned many names of god, such as EL, EL ELYON, YHVH. Does it imply us that god has many sons? From some sacred named such as Michael, Gabriel, I guess that the name of god is EL, but how about others? Is my guess correct that they are sons of god?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  If you haven't done so already, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and [this post](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) explaining how we are a little different than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your post, but rather a simple welcome message.*

Comment: Elohim is a very old word for "gods" that predates Moses by many years. The curious singular usage of it in the Bible, rather than plural, is unique to the Bible and Genesis, as far as I know. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elohim#Canaanite_religion In the other books of the Bible it is El, the singular of Elohim.

Answer (score 1):

The *name* of God, as we would think it today is [YHWH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton) (or YHVH, or Yahweh, or Jehovah, depending on how you want to translate the ancient Hebrew). The other names you are seeing are called 'names of God' in the Bible, but today we would think of them more as titles. Elohim is a particularly old one and frequently used in the Old Testament; some others are:

- El HaNe'eman - The Faithful God
- El HaKadosh - The Holy God
- El Yisrael - The God Of Israel

These are not sons of God, but different things that God is called.

Michael and Gabriel are archangels, and not names of God.

Here is [a helpful page on the names of God](http://www.allaboutgod.com/names-of-god.htm).

Comment: Elohim is simply the word for 'god' or 'gods'. It is technically plural, which is a discussion I'm sure has been had on [hermeneutics.se].

Comment: Thank you. How many sons does god the father have?

Comment: @believer If you want to ask another question, please click on the "Ask Question" link at the top of the page.